# How to update map property in dynamodb

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a map in dynamo with the following structure:

```json
 participants: {
      M: {
        "6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836": {
          M: {
            participantUid: {
              S: "6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836",
            },
            userSummary: {
              M: {
                userRef: {
                  S: "refGoesHere",
                },
              },
            },
            isRead: {
              BOOL: false,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

I'm trying to update the `isRead` property with the following command:

```js
const updateReadStatusCommand = new UpdateCommand({
      TableName: config.database,
      Key: {
        PK: `TASK#${taskUid}#CLIENT#${client}`,
        SK: `THREAD#${uid}`,
      },
      UpdateExpression: `SET participants.#participantUid.isRead = :isRead`,
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#participantUid": userUid,
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":isRead": updateBody.isRead,
      },
      ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    });
```

So far I keep running into the following error: `The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update`.

I'm struggling to see the issue here, as it won't recognise the property within the map. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

I've also scanned the table to ensure that the data is in the correct format and it looks like this:

```json
"participants": {
        "6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836": {
          "isRead": false,
          "participantUid": "6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836",
          "userSummary": {
            "userRef": "refGoesHere"
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: if you do find the correct answer to this, please post it, Im intrigued

Comment: The bad path error would be explained if you accidently saved the map in DynamDB JSON format.  Click on a table item in the console (go to `Item Editor`).  What attribute format do you see when `View DynamoDB JSON` is switched off?

Comment: I've just pasted what I scanned on the database :)

Comment: the UpdateExpression as a template string is bothering me too :D could you try with a standard " " string ?

Comment: No luck. I also double-checked what is being output in the command which is:

 UpdateExpression: 'SET #participants.#participantUid.#isRead = :isRead',
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#participantUid': '6ecd8c99-4036-403d-bf84-cf8400f67836',
            '#isRead': 'isRead',
            '#participants': 'participants'
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':isRead': true },

Answer (score 1):

I dont see much wrong with this, the only thing I can think of it trying to change -

```
UpdateExpression: `SET participants.#participantUid.isRead = :isRead`,
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
   "#participantUid": userUid,
},
...
```

to

```
UpdateExpression: `SET participants.#participantUid.#isRead = :isRead`,
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
   "#participantUid": userUid,
   "#isRead": "isRead"
},
...
```

in case `.isRead` is being treated as a string, rather than part of the path, as I noticed in the docs, like the example below, the use of `#3str` being used as `#pr.#3star` rather than using `#pr.ThreeStar` directly -

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"Id":{"N":"789"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET #pr.#5star[1] = :r5, #pr.#3star = :r3" \
    --expression-attribute-names file://names.json \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

(names.json)

```
{
    "#pr": "ProductReviews",
    "#5star": "FiveStar",
    "#3star": "ThreeStar"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Sadly it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I've also edited my post to reflect what's stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this due to an incorrect SK which meant that the document I wanted to update couldn't be found.

The query itself was correct. Leaving this here for anyone in a similar position, check you're actually trying to update the right thing!